# R ggplot 2 geom_line by year

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a `geom_line` plot `colored` by `month` with `tmean` at `y-axis` and `year` on `x-axis`. When I try the code on a sample dataset it produces the intended plot. However, when I run the code on my data, it doesn't return what I want.

How can I get the desired plot?

Code output with sample data:

```
library(tidyverse)

sample_df = data.frame(
    month = rep(1:6, each = 30),
    year = rep(1980:2009, 6),
    so2 = rnorm(180)
)

sample_df %>% 
               ggplot(aes(x = year, y = so2, color = as.character(month))) +
               geom_line() +
               ggtitle("Timeseries Plot By Month")
```

Output:

[image]

Code output with original data:

The data can be accessed [here](https://app.box.com/s/d5e56io6ym7t0d2hd68ph1pl6nd4d7uv). `dput` would have made the question way too long.

```
# Read CSV to df
df = read.csv("path")

             df %>% 
               ggplot(aes(x = year, y = tmean, color = as.character(month))) +
               geom_line() +
               ggtitle("Timeseries Plot By Month")
```

Output:

[image]

When I create the same desired plot on the same dataset in another software I get what I want (lines represent different plots in the below plot):

Desired output:

[image]

**Update**

Updated sample data

```
structure(list(tmean = c(31, 30, 32, 33, 34, 40, 41, 42, 43, 
46, 33, 36, 39, 32, 38, 42, 44, 48, 52, 56), month = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), year = c(1980, 
1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1980, 1980, 
1980, 1980, 1980, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try `ggplot(aes(x = year, y = tmean, color = as.character(month), group = month)) +`

Comment: So, your "sample data" works fine but your actual data doesn't? I'd suggest removing the sample data from the question as it seems pretty irrelevant to the question it it works. I'd also ask that you please use `dput` to share a **small sample** of your actual problematic data - just 3 or 4 years and 3 or 4 months each should be plenty to illustrate the problem. It's just much quicker and easier for anyone to help you by copy/pasting `dput` data than it is to download a file, move it to a working directory, read it in to R, wonder if there are class conversions that need doing...

Comment: And it also make the question a much better resource for future users to have data shared in the question.

Comment: To show a reproducible example, you might try `df = read.csv("path") %>% filter(year > 2015, month < 5)` or some variation to see how little data you can include and still replicate the issue.

Comment: Check your data. IMHO your data is messed up. According to your `Variable` column your tmean column contains mean, min and max values. Hence the "zig-zag" shape of the line.  While that could be fixed by filtering for `Variable=="tmean"` the second issue is that there are multiple (perhaps duplicated) observations for year-month pairs.

Comment: @GregorThomas, the reason why I did not post a sample from the original is because I did check the code on such a sample and the code works as intended. I can post it if you want.

Comment: @stefan, yes `tmean` column has the mean temperature column values. Secondly, there are multiple values for the same `month` is because the data is spatially distributed on `4km` grid.

Comment: No, please don't post more data that doesn't reproduce the problem. But sounds like Stefan stumbled on the solution--your sample data doesn't have multiple measurements but your real data does. You'll have to aggregate your data before plotting and decide whether you want the plot the sum, mean, median, max, min or some other aggregate statistic of your multiple measures.

Comment: @ JonSpring when I do `df %>% filter(year < 1981, month < 2)` I still get `174 rows`, can I put this `dput` in the question?

Comment: I'd also add that finding a minimal reproducible example that does reproduce the problem makes the problem much clearer - at least 3/4 of the questions I begin to post on Stack Overflow I end up solving myself in creating a nice small example. See [Jenny Bryan's fantastic talk on this subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgYS-F8opgE) for nice illustration.

Comment: @GregorThomas please see the updated sample data

Comment: So, when you have multiple values for the same year and month, what value do you want the line to go through? Mean, median, min, max, sum, something else....?

Comment: @GregorThomas, `mean`, I did try the following code that works on the updated sampled data but still doesn't quite work on the original data.  `aggregate(tmean ~ month + year,  Sample_df, FUN = mean) %>% ggplot(aes(x = year, y = tmean, color = as.character(month))) + geom_line()`

Comment: **Edit**: sorry the above ^ code is working now, should I post it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your data includes three values in the `Variable` column. You probably only want the ones where `Variable == "tmean"`, otherwise the data is all zeroes.
2. After that filter, you have 58 observations for each year-month, so you need some aggregation.

This might do it:

```
df %>% 
  filter(Variable == "tmean") %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  summarize(tmean = mean(tmean)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, tmean, color = as.factor(month))) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

---

###### How might you figure this out next time?

It's useful in data exploration, especially when you see something unusual, to investigate the data to see if it has the characteristics you should expect.

Your data has 88,000 rows. There are 42 different year values and 13 (?) different month values.

```
nrow(df)
[1] 87870

df %>% 
  summarize(across(c(year, month, Variable, tmean), n_distinct))
# A tibble: 1 × 4
   year month Variable tmean
  <int> <int>    <int> <int>
1    42    13        3 11943
```

If you had one value for each year-month, you'd expect around 546 observations. But you have 88,000, so there about 160 observations for each year-month, across 3 Variables. We can see that only the situations with `Variable == "tmean"` have any variation:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Variable) %>%
  summarize(n_values = n_distinct(tmean))
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Variable n_values
  <chr>       <int>
1 tmax            1
2 tmean       11942
3 tmin            1
```

We can also see that each year-month has 58 observations, and this is the case for all 505 year-months in the data.

```
df %>% 
  filter(Variable == "tmean") %>%
  count(year, month, name = "yearmo_obs") %>%
  add_count(yearmo_obs, name = "times_this_count")
# A tibble: 505 × 4
    year month yearmo_obs times_this_count
   <dbl> <dbl>      <int>            <int>
 1  1980     0         58              505
 2  1980     1         58              505
 3  1980     2         58              505
 4  1980     3         58              505
 5  1980     4         58              505
 6  1980     5         58              505
 7  1980     6         58              505
 8  1980     7         58              505
 9  1980     8         58              505
10  1980     9         58              505
# … with 495 more rows
```

You can observe the same sort of issues if you sort the data. We'd see here that there are multiple `tmean` values for points that have the same coordinates in the eventual plot:

```
>   df %>%
+     arrange(year, month)
# A tibble: 87,870 × 7
    ...1 tmean Variable  year month  TMin  TMax
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     3  24.4 tmean     1980     0     0     0
 2   510  24.5 tmean     1980     0     0     0
 3   511  24.5 tmean     1980     0     0     0
 4  1518  24.6 tmean     1980     0     0     0
 5  2027  24.2 tmean     1980     0     0     0
 6  2028  24.3 tmean     1980     0     0     0
 7  2029  24.2 tmean     1980     0     0     0
 8  3544  24.3 tmean     1980     0     0     0
 9  3545  24.3 tmean     1980     0     0     0
10  3546  24.3 tmean     1980     0     0     0
# … with 87,860 more rows
```

Those observations tell us we should filter by Variable and do some sort of aggregation if we want to show a single value per year-month with `geom_line`.

Comment: Yes, for some reason the data has the month `0` in it which is odd, I will remove this month.

Comment: thank you for the thorough guidance, I really appreciate it. One small thing though, if I plot `month` on `x-axis` the month values show up as `2.5` ,`3.5` and etc. on the axis. Since I don't want the month to show in decimal in the plot, I tried fixing it by doing `df$Month = lubridate::monht(df$month)` but it that does not fix it.

Comment: No worries scale_x_coniltinous fixes it

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the useful comments and the first answer, I also found another way of doing it so thought of adding it.

```
aggregate(tmean ~ month + year,       # Aggregate data
                           df,
                        FUN = mean) %>%
               ggplot(aes(x = year, y = tmean, color = as.factor(month))) +
               geom_line() +
               ggtitle("Timeseries Plot By Month")
```